Sensitivity of CoSi2 to hydrogen
It is known that palladium is quite sensitive to hydrogen, i.e., has an extraordinary ability to absorb hydrogen. I was reading a paper that talks about the fabrication of a Pd based sensor for hydrogen such that a Pd array may act as a sensor for detecting hydrogen concentrations.
Does anyone know if cobalt disilicide (CoSi2) is also sensitive to hydrogen?

If something has a prominent property, it's easy to find, but if it does not, it's simply not gonna be mentioned at all - pretty much impossible to verify. CoSi2 is very different than Pd, so I doubt it has similar properties. Definitely isn't as good with H2.

There is more research on hydrogen in silicides these days. In theory, silicides can have similar interstitial sites as cubic metals.
